# Loader hanging issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loading

I have a loader that loads main application. Everything works fine, except one issue:

When main application is loaded, animation in loader freezes for few seconds (5-8). I think during these 5-8 seconds main application creates it's objects.

I tried to minimize number of objects in main application and it did help a bit, but freezing problem is still there.

Does anybody had such issues? How to load content without freezing?

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming this is happening as the other SWF inside main is not complete, so whats happening is your "movie" loads the "second movie" , than the second "Movie" creates its objects at this time it freezes. This will happen because the second movie may have loaded but than its initializing all its content.

To solve this  you would need to either hide this second Movie until it has completly finish creating the objects than show its self, or creat a call in the second movie to let the first movie im finish doing my thing()

If you need be i have made an example of this some time ago which i could put on my server for you.